# Is there any difference between "take something up with someone" and "bring something up with someone"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is there any difference between *take something up with someone* and *bring something up with someone*? For example:

> We are going to **take** the issue **up** with the boss.
>
> We are going to **bring** the issue **up** with the boss.

Comment: If you ***bring*** something up with the boss, you're just (neutrally) *mentioning, raising, discussing* something that doesn't necessarily require anyone to adopt a strong position. But if you ***take*** something up with him, this would often imply you and he are in conflict over the matter, and/or that "something" is ***a situation that needs to be resolved***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bringing something up is like discussing a topic. It could be about anything.

Taking something up can be a bit more contentious, suggesting here that the issue may be *with* the boss himself, something he did, a disagreement over a decision he made, etc.